# How do I generate both "isSomething" and "getSomething" for boolean fields using Lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

I basically have a scenario where I need Lombok to generate getters for boolean fields to be "isSomething" and "getSomething".

I can't have one or the other -- I need both. I also don't want to add these manually as it's literally thousands of classes I would need to process.

Anyone know how to generate both a "is" and "get" getter using Lombok?

Comment: What a curious requirement. Why do you need two methods that do the same thing?

Comment: Good question, but there's a reason which is -- the majority of our codebase is already using the "is" variety so I can't change that. Recently we've implemented this stupid Spring Expression Language parser which expects ALL field accessors to start with "get".

Comment: I didn't think there wasn't a reason :) Can't you change the language parser?

Comment: I tried, it accepts some kind of MethodResolver (or something) but it doesn't quite do what I need it to do. I managed to fix the problem tho thanks to one of my colleagues. Turns out SPeL is looking for isIsSomething (not getSomething) so by removing the "is" from the field name is magically started working. Thanks for your help dude :)